# Foundation Range Slider Input doesn't change slider dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I want to change the input value and have the range slider move according to the input value dynamically. I want to know how to connect the input and the data-slider so it can work together.

```
function doSum() {
var slider_value = $(".range-slider").attr('data-slider');
$("#sliderOutput5").attr('value',slider_value);
var amount = slider_value;

var apr = $("#sliderOutput4");
var years = $("#sliderOutput3");
var payment = $("#payment");
var total = $("#total");
var totalinterest = $("#totalinterest");

var principal = parseInt(amount);
var interest = parseInt($(apr).val()) / 100 / 12;
var payments = parseInt($(years).val()) * 12;

var x = Math.pow(1 + interest, payments);
var monthly = (principal*x*interest)/(x-1);

payment.text(monthly.toFixed(2));
total.text((monthly * payments).toFixed(2));
totalinterest.text(((monthly*payments)-principal).toFixed(2));
              }

$(function() {
    $(".range-slider").on('change.fndtn.slider', function () {
    doSum();
});

    $('input').on('change', function () {
    doSum();
});
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/to0namiSB/kLp6chtw/)

Comment: There are a lot of work

Comment: Any tips to get in the right direction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value like so:

```
$('input').each(function(k,v) {
    $(v).keyup(function(e) {
        var $slider = $(v).parent().prev();
        $slider.foundation('slider', 'set_value', $(v).val());
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/kLp6chtw/4/)

See [Getting and setting values](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/range_slider.html) for more from the docs.

Comment: This works great but one question. When I click on the input then the range slider it stop updating the input box. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok let me give you how to start and go ahead from

```
$('.place').on('change',function(){
    var value = $(this).val(); 
    var sliderBar = $(this).parent().parent().find('.range-slider');
    var sliderHandle = $(this).parent().parent().find('.range-slider-handle');
    var sliderSpan = $(this).parent().parent().find('.range-slider-active-segment');
    sliderBar.attr('data-slider', value);
    sliderHandle.css('-webkit-transform', 'translateX(Newspacefromleft)').css( 'transform', 'translateX(Newspacefromleft)');
    sliderSpan.css('width','Newwidth');
});
```

you have to change all   of tha sliderBar ,sliderHandle  and sliderSpan  .use Inspect element in your browser to get a percentages you will need